# Sending an img file using Python

Tags: python, file, sockets

I am looking to send an img file created using Qemu snapshot feature through the network using Python. Its file is of varying size.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you perhaps elaborate on exactly what your problem is, so that we can help better. Warm welcome to STACKOVERFLOW, best site on the net.

Comment: What do you mean by "sending"? By email attachement? Over socket? FTP?

Comment: There isn't actually a question here.

Comment: I want to transfer an img file using the Sockets in Python. Is it possible?

Comment: @user1167385: Yes, yes it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may want to read the **socket** module doc of python.